# Recognition of snake (image)

Tags: species-identification, zoology, herpetology, snake

I would like some help with the recognition of the snake shown in the image below. I was doing a fieldwork in a forest in Slovakia when I found it.

I was thinking it could be a water snake but I am no expert in snakes. 
Does someone know what kind of snake is this?

[image: image of snake]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aesculapian snake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesculapian_snake) (*Zamenis longissimus*). Common european species, non venomous, rodent/egg eater.

edit1: they can swim and can be found next to water bodies but are terrestrial.